# Annotate private function in closure

Tags: javascript, annotations, closures, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

How would I annotate this private function called bar within a closure?

```
var Foo = (function() {
    var fn = (function() {
        return {
            bar: function(baz) {
                alert(baz);
            }
        };
    })();
    return {
        doBar: function(label) {
            fn.bar(label);
        }
    }
});
```

Like so?

```
/**
 * @type {function(string): string}
 * @private
 */
bar: function(baz) {
    return baz;
}
```

Or like so?

```
/**
 * @param {string}
 * @private
 * @return {string}
 */
bar: function(baz) {
    return baz;
}
```

Or even a combination of both docs? But then I would have duplicated information for the function's parameter and the return type I think.

```
/**
 * @param {string}
 * @private
 * @type {function(string): string}
 * @return {string}
 */
bar: function(baz) {
    return baz;
}
```

A complete jsDoc Example for the whole closure example. There are no @private jsDoc for the "private" functions anymore (like 'John' said).

```
/**
 * @type {function(): Object}
 * @public
 */
var Foo = (function() {
    /**
     * @type {function(): Object}
     * @private
     */
    var fn = (function() {
        return {
            /**
             * @param {string} baz Something to alert
             */
            bar: function(baz) {
                alert(baz);
            }
        };
    })();
    return {
        /**
         * @param {string} label A label string
         * @public
         */
        doBar: function(label) {
            fn.bar(label);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with your sample.  The label in the function does nothing.  Do you mean:
    var fn = (function() {
        return { bar: function(baz) {
            return baz;
        }};
    })();

Comment: Also, what are you expecting "@private" to mean in this case?

Comment: First of all it is just an example, but let me alert the label to make it more clear. With the @private I mean that the bar function is truly in private scope and not accessible from outside the instance of Foo. Foo.bar('bazz') is not possible whereas Foo.doBar('bazz') is accessible.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. your "var fn" is undefined.  The function you execute to define it has no return value.  As is, you have a labelled statement. What you want is return Object literal with the name bar:  return { 'bar': ... };

AFAIK Closure's "@private" is file-based (it can only be considered private to a file, not an instance).  In your example, it isn't necessary to annotate a method "@private" because it is structurally hidden by the way you define "Foo". There is no object (assume it is corrected to do what you intended) exposed that contains a property "bar".

Comment: Indeed I forgot to return it. Corrected that.

Comment: @John: I added an extra example with no "@private" in the private functions' docblocks.